# Uninstalling Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, uninstallation, xcode4.3

I have Xcode 4.3 installed on Mac OS Lion, but I can't find a way to uninstall it. Any ideas?
I have no 
`/Xcode4/Library/uninstall-devtools` (can't find an Xcode4 folder) or 
`/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools`(Library folder doesn't exist under Developer)

I have a `Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode` with:

- DerivedData
- UserData
- Installs
- iOS DeviceSupport

I have `/Developer` with

- Applications
- Documentation
- Extras
- Platforms

The only other place I could find a reference to Xcode was in `Applications/Xcode.app`
Is there something I've overlooked? I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You uninstall Xcode 4.3 like you would uninstall most Mac applications, by moving it to the Trash. Xcode 4.3 is bundled as a single application so there's no need for an uninstall script.

Comment: Incorrect. xCode is not bundled in single application. There are associated libraries. Dragging to Trash does not clean up the associated libraries.

Comment: Have you used Xcode 4.3? What you are saying is correct in earlier versions of Xcode, but Xcode 4.3 changed things. Instead of a folder at /Developer, Xcode 4.3 bundles everything inside the Xcode app. There is no uninstall-devtools script and no installer for Xcode in Xcode 4.3

Comment: So what does this mean then? Everything associated to Xcode seems to be at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents`

Comment: If you want a really clean uninstall, you should also consider deleting preference files in ~/Library/Preferences/ (e.g. com.apple.dt.Xcode* - same holds for iPhoneSimulator and Instruments). Other directories to check are ~/Library/Developer and its subfolders as well as ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator. However, if you plan a clean reinstall, you might want to backup data from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode, e.g. Application Archives, device logs or screenshots.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk 's answer is correct. Xcode doesn't have any uninstaller anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Maurizio Zilli:

"In new Xcode 4 and Lion You can install and uninstall from Preferences : downloads : components

If You want to uninstall completely XCode go to launchpad and push Xcode icon for two seconds, so click on the upper left checkbox."

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3784638?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: The Launchpad anwer sounded strange to me, but i think it's right. It may take a while until everything is gone.

Comment: Just pushing the button wouldn't let me click the "X" that showed but holding the Option key to show the "X" (remove) buttons on applications that can be removed in this manner worked fine.  It took a few minutes but did delete XCode from the Applications directory itself and XCode now shows in the App Store with an Install button.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall xcode 4.3.x **simply drag the Xcode.app to the trash**. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

There's still some large docset files in `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/`. You could search for other support files with `mdfind -name xcode -0 | xargs -0 du -sm | sort -rn`.

For some reason, `/Library/Developer/` wasn't removed when I installed Xcode 4.3. It contained about 2GB of old docset files.