# How to uninstall Xcode 4..3.3 completely from the Mac OS

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstalling Xcode 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478410/uninstalling-xcode-4-3)

Please suggest how i can completely uninstall the Xcode 4.3.3 from my Mac.As i have tried this command on Terminal 
"sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all"
But its not working.Can anyone suggest me how to get it done.

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: This is more a question for http://superuser.com. Consider to post it there. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, by **moving it to the Trash**.There's no need for an uninstall scrip because  Xcode 4.3 is bundled as a single application .

Comment: More or less correct, but won't uninstall command line tools etc.

Comment: will it work for Xcode4.5.2