# How to uninstall Xcode 5.0.2 from MAC 10.9

Tags: xcode, macos

Using MAC OS X 10.9, want to uninstall Xcode 5.0.2 and want to install again Xcode 5.0.2

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uninstalling Xcode 4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478410/uninstalling-xcode-4-3) or [How to fully remove Xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5255959/457406)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just drag and drop Xcode to trash from app folder

Comment: Have a backup of your xcode.dmg file...then do it

Comment: @Samkit...Yes i have xcode.dmg file. So rite now i just need to drag the Xcode to trash from application folder and then what i have to do ???

Comment: Yes..please do...it will get uninstalled

Comment: @Samkit...OK i done that, now i have to type something on terminal as well ?

Comment: Samkit.. its showing Xcode can't be move to trash bcuz it is open. I dont know why this is showing. I closed xcode already.

Comment: Try using force quit and then try that....force quit xcode..then try...if still same persists..restart system and try the same

Comment: Done. thank you Samkit, moved to trash ... now tell me how im going to install Xcode ?

Comment: Simple run your dmg file and install man

Comment: ok i dragged the xcode into application folder, and its installed now.  so now i need to something else or it is completely installed ???

Comment: No need to do...just make a shortcut by dragging to your dock ...if you want?

Comment: @samkit...one more thing. now i need to connect simulator with xcode . i clicked on simulator but its showing message that cant run bcuz original file is in trash .. now what to do?

Comment: It will come automatically...jus download a sample app and run it ...using Command + R

Comment: @Samkit...i already did, when im running any application in xcode it is running on simulator but the only simulator is not opening when im clicking on it. saying "The Alias IOS simulator cant be open bcuz original item is in trash"

Comment: yes i have, manish@developer.datainfovision.com 
coming online ???

Comment: reason for vote down?

Comment: Simply moving apps to trash leaves many configuration files left on you hard drive. This way you can only remove files stored inside .app folder. MAC also stores configuration files in Library folder.

Comment: @SamkitJain : Well I didn't downvote :)

Comment: Ok if you want to properly uninstall and keep your mac clean from bits and pieces of system files, you should get app cleaner! I RECOMMEND IT!

Comment: This does not remove Xcode settings.

Answer (score 33):

Using [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) will make your life easier. You can use drag an drop for uninstalling any app you have installed on your Mac, and it is free to use.

[image]

[image]